# angular serialize $http request

Tags: angularjs, http, serialization

I want to request data when former data is received.
I'm using below code but looks messy.

```
$http(url: 'data1')
 .success( function(data) { $http(url: 'data2') 
 .success( function(data) { $http(url: 'data3')
 ..... }) }) }) }) }) ...
```

--------old code (not serialized but simple)--------------------

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
  $http(url: 'data' + i).success( function(data) { ...})
}
```

any idea of this?

Comment: Maybe you're overthinking this? I mean, is the remota data array dynamic? If not, what do you really gain by refactoring it into a for-loop?

Comment: Data should come orderly. it's really matter which data comes first.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.factory("mySvc", function() {

    var function1 = function() {
        return $http(url: 'data1');
    }
    var function2 = function() {
        return $http(url: 'data2');
    }
    return {
        function1: function1,
        function2: function2
    }
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, mySvc, $q) {

    $q.all([
        mySvc.function1(),
        mySvc.function2()
    ]).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result[0]); // data from function1
        console.log(result[1]); // data from function2
    })

});
```

Comment: your code is not sure that which data comes first. I need to make sure that every datas comes to 'orderly'

Comment: this data will come accodingly it placed in $q.all .

Comment: but it cannot work before all data come in. I want to do my process whenever data is completly received or not BUT orderly.